# Grails - How to Unit Test addTo*

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

Is it possible to unit test addTo* functions in Grails ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to actually test the functionality of the `addTo*` methods, or are you simply looking to mock them out for other tests? Testing the methods provided by the framework is largely unnecessary - if they don't work, it's a bug with the framework, not your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation [says in section 9.1](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing):

> In Grails you need to be particularity
>   aware of the difference between unit
>   and integration tests because in unit
>   tests Grails **does not** inject any of
>   the dynamic methods present during
>   integration tests and at runtime.

You either have to use `mockDomain(DomainClassName)`  in a unit test
or write an integration test:

Grails decorates domain object with some Dynamic methods when the `DomainClassGrailsPlugin` gets setup(`doWithDynamicMethods`).

Comment: `mockDomain` doesn't appear to mock the `addTo` methods unfortunately... At least not in Grails 2.2.1

Comment: I believe something changed in 2.2.x - you may have to mock both sides of the relationship now.

Comment: I think it might be http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9637 fixed in 2.2.1:  Also see the release notes for 2.2.1 http://grails.org/2.2.1%20Release%20Notes

Answer (score 2):

I hit this problem in upgrading from Grails 2.1.2 to Grails 2.3.x.  Where as before you only needed to mock the domain class you are adding to, now you need to also mock the domain class being added.  Simple with Annotations.

```
@TestFor(YourService)
@Mock([MyClass, MyOtherClass])
class YourServiceTests {
  .... //now myClass.addToMyOtherClasses(myOtherClassInstance) should work fine in your test or in the code being tested
}
```