# Grails Unit test and mocking addTo

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am trying to test the override of equals in a domain object to ensure that 'contains' works.  The unit test mechanics are defying me, in spite of documentation and bugs saying that I should be able to mock addTo.

My test is:

```
@TestFor(Member)
@Mock([Member])
class MemberCategoryTests {

  void testContains() {
    MemberCategory schoolCat = new MemberCategory(name: "SCHOOL")
    MemberCategory membersCat = new MemberCategory(name: "Members")
    Member member = new Member(membershipNumber: "333333",
            surname: "Tester",
            forenames: "Jim",
            preferredEmail: "mmm@yyy.com")
    member.addToMemberCategories(schoolCat)
    member.addToMemberCategories(membersCat)

    MemberCategoryRedback memberCategoryRedback = new MemberCategoryRedback(name: "SCHOOL")
    assert member.memberCategories.contains(memberCategoryRedback)
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
No signature of method: au.com.interlated.civiLink.Member.addToMemberCategories() is applicable for argument types: (au.com.interlated.civiLink.MemberCategory)
```

The domain object isn't special. MemberCategory implements equals.

This document says @Mock([yyy]) should do the trick: [Naleid upgrading to grails 2 testing](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/05/01/upgrading-to-grails-2-unit-testing) as does [unit testing addto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754616/grails-how-to-unit-test-addto)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel you need two changes to make it work

1.Add `MemberCategory` to `@TestFor`, because your trying to add members to membercategirt then your code will become like this:

```
@TestFor(MemberCategory)  
@TestFor(Member)
```

2.Also call `save()` after adding `member.addToMemberCategories(membersCat)`, then your code will become some thing like this

```
if(!member.save(validate: true,flush:true,failOnError: true)) {    
   member.errors.each {    
      log.debug(it)   
   }   
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes - the extra @TestFor removes the error from the question. I can't confirm that saving is required as the test reports that contains() isn't working either way. Thanks